# Managing external code errors

Tags: openmdao

I am trying to run an external code in OpenMDAO 2 that outputs some minor error messages as part of it's run process in windows shell. These error messages does not affect the results of the code and the code runs itself normally. However OpenMDAO raises a fault and stops whenever it detects these error messages. Is it possible for OpenMDAO to ignore such situation and continue running the analysis? I have tried setting fail_hard option to false, but it doesn't seem to change the behavior except that OpenMDAO raises analysis error instead of run-time error.

Comment: can you provide a simple example of the type of errors you're raising? I suspect that you're outputting to stderr and that the subprocess is seeing that as an exception. But without an example its hard to offer help

Comment: @JustinGray, yes external code is running from a batch file and outputting to stderr. The specific error message that raises a fault is "( was unexpected at this time" that is due to some symbols inside the script misinterpreted by windows shell. Final error line from openmdao looks like this:
  `File "C:\Users\44369\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\components\external_code.py", line 176, in compute
    err_fragment))
openmdao.core.analysis_error.AnalysisError: return_code = 255
Error Output:
& was unexpected at this time.`

Answer (score 0):

We can implement a feature to let you specify allowable return codes.. as long as you can enumerate which return codes are not errors, I think this will solve your problem?

Comment: So as far as I understood, the only option currently available is to fix the external code so it does not output any error messages to stderr?